# Build SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) for web application

Tags: php, web-services, soa

I need a help,
i am newbie for SOA(Service Oriented Archetecture)

how to start to build SOA for web application?

i have tried exproled, i still cannot found how to build SOA and use what to build SOA

can some one help me?
i need use what software or aplication to build soA for web application

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to start to build SOA for web application?

Not sure exactly what you mean but you probably start by writing lines of code, preferably test code.

> i have tried exproled, i still cannot found how to build SOA and use
>   what to build SOA

Again, I can't be sure , but you probably want to be doing something like this:

- write a test
- make it pass
- refactor as appropriate
- repeat

Also, read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture

> i need use what software or aplication to build soA for web
>   application

You can use any software platform or technology stack you like to actually write the code with. If you're using PHP, then why not stick with PHP?

Maybe try a [framework](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=soa+php+frameworks).

Maybe also look at this: http://symfony.com/what-is-symfony

Comment: Tq for answer and thanks for the link you get.. very help